# My pilea is developing large dark patches. No evidence of mites or root rot

Tags: plant-health

This happened practically overnight on two lower leaves only. I wait for soil to dry between waterings. It's been happy for the few months I've had it growing babies etc. I checked the roots and they seem fine. 
The patches seem to be starting at the centre of the lower leaves and spreading outward.
I want to stop whatever this is from spreading to my, otherwise healthy, plant.[image: pilea peperomioides]